# WooCommerce: How to find a piece of code I modified for disabling the "Add to Cart" function?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I made a webshop in WooCommerce. The client wanted to avoid the original webshop, so I made a form for the client to order the products. I can't remember, how or where, I modified a PHP file to disable the **Add to Cart** function. Fortunately, I have the original theme files, but am afraid to break something. Can you guys help me please?

I tried to check my CSS to see if I disabled it there, but it was not there.
Also, checked the `function.php` file, but I can't recall what I changed.

I need to roll back the webshop as it initially was. With its **Add to Cart** button again.

Please take a look at the code:

**woocommerce.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce
 * Plugin URI: https://woocommerce.com/
 * Description: An eCommerce toolkit that helps you sell anything. Beautifully.
 * Version: 3.5.4
 * Author: Automattic
 * Author URI: https://woocommerce.com
 * Text Domain: woocommerce
 * Domain Path: /i18n/languages/
 *
 * @package WooCommerce
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

// Define WC_PLUGIN_FILE.
if ( ! defined( 'WC_PLUGIN_FILE' ) ) {
    define( 'WC_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );
}

// Include the main WooCommerce class.
if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
    include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/class-woocommerce.php';
}

/**
 * Main instance of WooCommerce.
 *
 * Returns the main instance of WC to prevent the need to use globals.
 *
 * @since  2.1
 * @return WooCommerce
 */
function wc() {
    return WooCommerce::instance();
}

// Global for backwards compatibility.
$GLOBALS['woocommerce'] = wc();
```

**function.php**

```
<?php

/* Load child theme stylesheet */
function amourchild_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'amourparent-theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'amourchild-childtheme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'amourchild_theme_style' , 10);

/* Insert custom functions below */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', true );

/**
 * @snippet       Adds prefix and/or suffix to WooCommerce Prices (conditionally per category)
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @source        https://businessbloomer.com/?p=472
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 2.4.7
 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_price_prefix_suffix', 100, 2 );

function bbloomer_price_prefix_suffix( $price, $product ) {

    // change 'audio' with your the category slug
    if ( has_term( 'everyday-bouquets', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $price = 'From ' . $price . '';
    } 

    if ( has_term( 'everyday-bouquets', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $product_price = 'From ' . $product_price . '';
    }

    if ( has_term( 'designers-choice', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $price = 'From ' . $price . '';
    } 

    // no need to put the else! $price will stay the same

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}

/**
 * Change currency display in WooCommerce
 * Put this in your functions.php file
 *
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'USD': $currency_symbol = 'US$ '; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'prefix_custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
/**
 * Hide Product Cateories from targetted pages in WooCommerce
 * @link https://gist.github.com/stuartduff/bd149e81d80291a16d4d3968e68eb9f8#file-wc-exclude-product-category-from-shop-page-php
 *
 */
function prefix_custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if( is_shop() || is_page(‘my-shop-page’) ) { // set conditions here
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

        $tax_query[] = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
               'field'    => 'slug',
               'terms'    => array( 'romance' ), // set product categories here
               'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );


        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

Comment: Chances are that the code you used for this is in your theme's `functions.php`. I'd look there.

Comment: Hi Hector. The problem is I don't know which line I modified. I've been looking for the "Add to Cart" function in this particular file but can't find it.

Comment: You'll have to edit your question to include your code so we can help you debug. Otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thank you, Hector. Let me do it.

Comment: If you meddled with the woocommerce theme, either you wrote a hook, added it in the function.php (which you dont know) or you actually wrote it in the original woocommerce files. Assuming you did the last, you may wanna check in either the functions folder (not wise to meddle with this) or check the theme-functions.php in the includes folder of woocommerce

Comment: Thank you Dorvalla. How can I upload the php files here so you guys can help me look?

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question, Joseph. Do so to include your code so we can have a look. Alternatively, upload it somewhere (eg. pastebin), post a new comment with the link and someone can edit your question for you with the code.

Comment: This is the Pastebin link for the function.php of the childtheme I'm using.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Fu7Wixcc

Comment: woocommerce.php
https://pastebin.com/r6kkx2Tg

Comment: Nothing in your child theme's `functions.php` file seems to be meddling with WC's Add-to-cart button so, as Dorvalla suggested, you either made changes to the WC plugin directly or you customized WC's templates by copying its files into your theme's folder. Do you have a `woocommerce` folder in your theme's directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fortunately, I have the original theme files, but am afraid to break
>   something. Can you guys help me please?

That's something good point to start with.

I would compare the original theme files with the current theme files to see what changes I have made. You can do it either through text editors or through special utility programs freely available on the Internet.

**Disclaimer**: *As I am on Windows OS so below instructions are valid for Windows OS, but same procedure can be used on any OS*

If I were in such situation, I would do it something like that:

1. Create a new folder **Test** on my local machine where I can save original theme files and current theme files.
2. Download current theme folder with all it's files to the **Test** folder. Suppose the current theme folder name is **current-theme**.
3. Copy the original theme folder with all it's files to the **Test** folder. Suppose the original theme folder name is **original-theme**.
4. Download and install [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/?lang=en). *WinMerge is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows*.
5. After installation, go to **Test** folder.
6. Select both folders i.e. **current-theme** and **original-theme**.
7. Right Click and select WinMerge.
8. It will popup **WinMerge Folder Comparison** view. Focus on the **Comparison result** column, where you can find the files with differences.

[image: Folder Comparison Results]

9. Hit Enter key on the file that has **Text files are different** in the *Comparison result** column.
10. It will open the selected file in a new tab. Here you can see all the differences in both files highlighted with color codes.

[image: File Comparison]

Now you can revert back to the original files after knowing what changes you have made earlier.

WinMerge's [quick tour](http://tour.winmerge.org/) describes the features and option in one page.

Comment: Kashif, I did and I found the problem. I deleted a piece of code that was in the original file. This particular piece of code was responsible for displaying and enabling the "Add to Cart" functionality. Many thanks for your help.